# How can I set enum in my userSchema to have an empty default

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am currently working on a registration form for a project using MongoDB as the database, ExpressJS, and PassportJS, however, I am trying to make the user to be able to choose the rol and then being registered in the database like that to redirect to the proper page once the user is logged in.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['COMPANY', 'IRONHACKER', 'ADMIN'],
        default: 'IRONHACKER',
    },
    session: String,
    last_login: {
        type: Date,
        default: ""
    }
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at"
    },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

By default it has 3 values, and users will only be able to pick 2: IRONHACKER and COMPANY.

Currently, its behavior is different, since I set "IRONHACKER" as the default one, it is always the one users get once the registered.

Comment: Could you explain the importance of being empty? So that I can imagine the scenery.

Comment: The importance of being empty is that if I currently register a user, it will automatically have a value assigned by default regardless of the role he really has, be it IRONHACKER, which is a student profile and the main actions I'm looking for this role is to fill up a profile and search for jobs, the other role is EMPLOYER which is basically the company that will be posting, deleting and reviewing students submissions. Each one of these has to access to different pages and the actions they can perform would be different.

Comment: So I read the documentation. Note that the enum is basically a validation rule of what can and can not be entered in the field. The insertion of something that does not exist breaks this rule. Perhaps this is not the way, it may be necessary to insert a fourth rule. A rule of only using the database.

Comment: I understand you point, maybe I have to use something different to be able to get the result I’m expecting, because even though I added a fourth rule stills not letting the user to pick its role and record it in the database.

Comment: Based on this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3044. Have you tried `[null, 'COMPANY', 'IRONHACKER', 'ADMIN']` and `default: null`? Or just `default: null`?

Comment: In case the user will have these two options available IRONHACKER AND COMPANY and in case you do not choose any of them you would like it to be empty or undefined?

Comment: It would be empty.

Comment: I thought the following, remove the default and add the fourth rule, and create a pre validation middleware to validate the fourth rule, if not selected A and B do C. What do you think?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, let me add that validation and I’ll tell you how everything went, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this and it actually worked out perfectly!

I kept the userSchema the same

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['COMPANY', 'IRONHACKER', 'ADMIN'],
        default: 'IRONHACKER',
    },
    session: String,
    last_login: {
        type: Date,
        default: ""
    }
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at"
    },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

And the only thing I modified was the signup form configuration: (The signup won't have this feature it was only for test purposes).

```
    <h2>Signup</h2>

<form action="/signup" method="POST" id="form-container">
  <label for="name">Full Name</label>
  <input id="name" type="name" name="name" placeholder="Provide your Name">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Set Username">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Set a password"> 
  <br>
  <br>
  <select name="role" id="role">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="IRONHACKER">Ironhacker</option>
    <option value="COMPANY">Employer</option>
    <option value="ADMIN">Administrator</option>
  </select>
  {{#if message}}
    <div class="error-message">{{ message }}</div>
  {{/if}}
  <br>
  <br>
  <button>Create account</button>

  <p class="account-message">
    Do you already have an account?
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
  </p>
</form>
```

So it now detects the role and user is given the role and permissions properly.